# Problem running TestNG project using CMD commands

Tags: java, maven, testng

I have a problem that I have not been able to solve for several days now (I have been through all of Google already)

I try to run my entire project (TestNG) tests through the CMD.
When I run the project with `mvn -X package` It runs the whole project.
The problem starts when I make a change to my TestNG.xml file, so that it only runs some of the tests. So the same command (`mvn -X package`) does not work, and it continues to run all the tests.
When I try to use a command from the Internet to run the project as TestNG
`java org.testng.TestNG TestNG.xml`(With all the variations I found)
It always shows me the same error message "Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG"

I see that many times they use LIB and BIN folders that I do not have, I only have SRC (I work through intellij) and I have no idea what needs to be put in place or just how to create those folders .

P.S
I have noticed that many have encountered this problem, but there is no answer that has been able to help me

**pom.xml**
`     

4.0.0

```
<groupId>SimplyClub.Tests.SubTotalTest</groupId>
<artifactId>SimplyTest</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>simplyclub.test.infrastructur</groupId>
        <artifactId>SimplyClub</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <systemPath>${user.home}/IdeaProjects/SimplyTestInfrastructure/out/artifacts/SimplyTestInfrastructure_jar/SimplyTestInfrastructure.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>



<properties>

   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>TestNG.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!--<source>1.8</source>-->
                <!--<target>1.8</target>-->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`

**TestNG.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="SimplyTest">
<listeners>
    <listener class-name = "utilities.Listeners"></listener>
</listeners>

<test name="Sub Total">
    <classes>
        <class name="Tests.SubTotalTest"></class>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="TranEnd">
    <classes>
        <class name="Tests.TranEndTest"></class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

**update:**
This is what appears to me after I run the command `mvn package`
no errors

**update2:**
So after all the installation of the plugins, there is progress
But now it presents me with another error that I can not understand
`org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-`    enter code here`plugin:3.1:testCompile`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrRQb.png)

I also updated the POM.xml

Comment: "So the same command (mvn -X package) does not work". What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: Remove `<version>RELEASE</version>` this and replace it with a correct version number...furthermore remove `<scope>Tests.SubTotalTest</scope>` and replace it with `<scope>test</scope>`...also in another dependency remove `<scope>Tests.SubTotalTest</scope>`.... simply wrong...

Comment: Please check your build on plain command line via `mvn package` there should be already warning maybe errors..

Comment: @tgdavies
The command, it does not run the tests that it registers there, it runs all the tests that are in the project

Comment: @khmarbaise
I made the changes you recorded, did not solve the problem

Comment: @khmarbaise
I updated my answer with a picture of what it presents to me

Comment: I'm not a testng user, but I would try making the name `testng.xml`. Also, exactly where is the file located?

Comment: @tgdavies 
The problem is not with the name, it is able to run the project through TestNg.xml and not through maven

And the XML file is in the main folder of the project

Answer (score 0):

Here are the list of problems that I am seeing within your pom file which you need to fix them

- `<scope>Tests.SubTotalTest</scope>`

As pointed out by others, this is not a valid value for scope. Please either remove it (it would then default to `compile` which means that the dependency is going to be available for all java classes in both `src/main/java` and in `src/test/java`)

- `<version>RELEASE</version>`

This does not resolve to any proper version. Please replace this with an actual version `7.4.0` (latest TestNG released version as of today) or use a proper maven variable (I don't think you need that right now because it would be an overkill)

For your tests to be executed as defined in your suite xml file, you need to configure surefire plugin accordingly. If not done, surefire plugin will always run all the test classes it can find (by default it looks for files that have `Test` (or) `TestCase` in the file name). You can learn more about this on the surefire plugin documentation.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
    <configuration>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

For the tag `<suiteXmlFile>` add the location of your `testng.xml` file (relative file location from the root directory of your project) and then surefire plugin will ONLY run the tests that are mentioned in the suite file.

Read more about maven surefire plugin from their documentation at http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html

Comment: First of all thank you for the response!
I updated the POM file in my response
I made the changes and it still did not work
I'm now testing using `<suiteXmlFile>`
  Hope this helps me

Comment: I dont see the surefire plugin entry in your pom file. I say this because your screenshot still shows that you are using surefire plugin version 2.12.4 but if you had added the above mentioned plugin entry into your pom file under `<build><plugins>` section, I should have seen the `3.0.0-M5` version. Please cross check.

Comment: I just updated the question, you can see I added it
But another error pops up for me now
`org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile`

Comment: Sounds like you have a lot of compilation errors. Please make sure that whatever jars you need, you aren't adding them via the IDE but they all need to go into your pom file as `<dependencies>`. You would need to fix your compilation errors by looking at your test code and seeing what imports are being used and from where are they coming in and add the appropriate dependencies.

Comment: And please get rid of the dependencies on compiler plugin and surefire plugin (remove them from `<dependencies>` tag, because you dont need them there). They need to be available only under `<build><plugins>` section. You aren't building a custom plugin so you don't need them.

Comment: ok, i have done it all that i left there were things that i use.  But I still get the same error